# Why do you say <Я пошёл> when should be present tense

Tags: tense

The expression <я пошёл к себе> is in the past tense but it means "I'm off home" which is the present tense. Why is this?

Comment: Great question. Injunctive mood (declaration of intent) in this particular case is indeed expressed with a past tense verb. Even though there is an equally common expression "Я пойду к себе".

Comment: Do not compare tenses used in a similar context in different languages! This won't help you. You are comparing completely different phrases and trying to make some conclusions on wrong assumptions.

Comment: @Bob Daley Note that this expression could also be interpreted as "I'm on a journey to myself".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about comparing completely different phrases in Russian and English.

Comment: @Abakan since it already has answers which could be of value to readers of the site i don't think closing the question is a prudent idea, or it may be put on hold so the answers stay

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка  In my opinion, this question, as it is now, has no use for learning or better understanding of Russian. Comparing a random English phrase to its apparent Russian translation doesn't make any sense. Otherwise we can end with questions "_Why do we say "Untill date/meeting" in Russian while it means "Good bye" which is completely different in English_" or  "_Why is дом in Russian masculine but it means "das Haus" in German which is neuter?_" etc.

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка "Я пошел к себе" means "I went home" which is also past tense. So there is no question to ask at all.

Comment: @Abakan A phrase "Я пошёл к себе" could be used at the end of a conversation where one speaker indicates his intent of going home.  Hence using past tense for a future action is very unusual.

Comment: @Vitaly Not more unusual than using present continuous for future actions: "I'm visiting my parents next week".

Comment: @Abakan Using present continuous for future actions is a common pattern. But I can't come up with another example of using Russian verbs in past tense to indicate intent.

Comment: @Vitaly You're right. But still this fact has no relation to the question.

Comment: So am I correct that < Я пошёл> means both I left and I am leaving?

Comment: Yes you are correct. It could be either, depending on the context. In the future, please ask such questions in the comments. You have sufficient privilege now.

Comment: @Vadim Landa he cannot appeal to himself because he's THE author, and this request for clarification is at all addressed to the respondents

Comment: @Abakan: This question is good, though the idiomatic English translation is a distraction. It asks about a construction that could puzzle any learner (or even a native speaker), because the past tense is used to express a present state of mind concerning a future action.

Answer (score 5):

For reasons unknown to me, verbs of movement with prefix *"по-"* are used in the past tense to indicate intent.

In general, prefix *"по-"* means the beginning of an action when used with any of the following verbs of movement: *бежать, вести, везти, гнать, ехать, катить, лезть, лететь, нести, плыть, ползти, тащить, идти.*

As a result the following phrases are used as farewells:

> - Я пошёл. / I'm leaving.
> - Я побежал. / I'm leaving in a hurry.
> - Я поехал. / I'm leaving by car, or public transport.

In a similar way the following phrases mean the intent of starting an action in the immediate future:

> Я понёс. / I am starting carrying [it].
>
> Я покатил. / I am starting rolling [it].

Usage of verbs in past tense for that purpose is unusual. A popular Russian writer [K. Chukovsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korney_Chukovsky) says in his book "Alive as life itself":

> Или эта форма: *я пошел* вместо *я ухожу.* Человек еще сидит за столом, он только собирается уйти, но изображает свой будущий поступок уже совершенным.
>   С этим я долго не мог примириться.
>
> *Or this form: "я пошел", instead of "я ухожу". The man is still sitting at the table, he just started contemplating his leave, but he expresses his future action as complete. For a long time I could not accept it.*

Comment: Could it be that it is some sort of contracted subjunctive, where бы is omitted? (Just a wild idea from a beginner!)

Comment: Or could it be similar to the way the Dutch say “ik had al gegeten” (I had already eaten) to express “I was so disgusted that I lost my appetite”?

Comment: @PJTraill It doesn't look like using past tense for beginning of an action is related to the two examples provided. However, Russians also use past tense for imperatives/orders, e.g. _"Побежал!" - "Start running!"_, or _"Упал, отжался!" - "Drop down and start push ups!"_ So when referring to oneself the speaker may reflect the need of starting the action. That's a personal opinion, not the official grammar.

Answer (score 1):

> <sup>I would say it's akin to Present Perfect in terms of English grammar,  because the verb is in perfective aspect, i.e. the act has been performed and its effect is still being felt at present.</sup>
>
>
> <sup><sup>So into English it would have to be translated as</sup></sup>
>
> > <sup><sup>*I have gone to Seva*</sup></sup>
>
> <sup>The question has probably been misunderstood because of a spelling mistake, so the response is "off home".</sup>

---

2nd attempt

Provided the Russian here is **Я пошёл к сеБе** (not **севе**) i believe one cannot meaningfully compare these two sentences because their structures are markedly different, it's only fair to compare more or less grammatically equivalent constructs.

Russian does have a construct similar to **I'm off home**, and that's **Я домой**, whose tense is equivalent to that of the English expression.

With a verb this idea can be expressed in all 3 tenses with a varying degree of determination (in a descending order)

> Я пошёл домой
> Я иду домой
> Я пойду домой

Comment: Regarding your comment "the act has been performed and its effect is still being felt at present", I assume the same goes for the past perfective verbs in these two instances: "Все еще по уши **увяз** в работе?" and "Я не **привык** тебя видеть здесь." Both past perfective verbs are translated as "you **are buried** in .." and "I'**m not used** to seeing ..." in the present tense in English, I take it?

Comment: @Alone-zee it's noteworthy that English translations of these sentences use not verbs but participles and it's only the verb **to be** which is in present tense and indeed in the Russian sentences the verbs have an undertone of a participle, **увязший** and **привыкший** respectively, which describe a state and not an action, so another way of translating the OP's sentence so that its tense is simple present is **I'm gone to Seva**, another case of using participle

Comment: So the real key is that Russian has no separate Present and Past Perfect tense.

Comment: @Bob Daley probably wanted to say *"Я пошёл к себе",* which means *"I'm off home"*

Comment: `Я пошёл к сеБе (not севе)` - it could also be "к Севе" though of less probability :-D

Answer (score 1):

*пошёл* has perfective [verb aspect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_aspect) - verbs with prefixes usually do. It refers to a one-time event of starting to walk. If you're walking right now, that event of starting to walk is already in the past.

*шёл* would be the corresponding imperfective aspect, referring to a habitual or continuous process of walking in the past.

Comment: Why do we use a perfective aspect of the verb for the action that one plans to do (i.e. not yet performed)? As in the farewell one says, "Я пошёл".

Comment: @Vitaly You mean why past tense? I'm afraid I don't have a good answer to that one. It might be an implicit "I've already made up my mind, please don't try to stop me".

Answer (score 0):

Because this is when you start your journey home. When I start my journey, I say: «я пошла к себе.» But when I went and that’s all done, I don’t say «я пошла», I say «я шла». Pretty simple for some but harder for others

Comment: I have voted up although I think this answer needs work and is hard to understand. Two reasons: I think the poster has something to contribute; I do not like to see an answer, especially from a new contributor, voted down with no explanatory comments.