# What verb is considered omitted in the expression "Я вообще-то про X и Y"?

Tags: глаголы, выражения

> Я вообще-то **про** X и Y...

The speaker used this expression to set her interlocutor straight on who she was actually referring to. I'm assuming this is an equivalent of:

> Actually, I was **talking**/**thinking** about X and Y.
>
> {or}: Actually, I **meant** X and Y.

I wonder if it is common to omit a verb (whatever it is) from this Russian expression.

Answer (score 4):

Yes and Yes.

The construct with the verb omission exists also outside of this specific expression. **`Я о/про + object`** means **`I'm speaking of/mean...`** when used as a clarification either solicited or self-initiated.

The omission is similar to that in a phrase ***речь о...***, where the verb ***идёт*** gets omitted, Russian for ***it's about...***

Another expression of this type which came up in [a response to another question](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/16227/7674) is ***Я домой / на работу / в кино*** where the verb ***иду*** is dropped - ***I'm off home / to work / to the movies***.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is common to omit a verb. Especially if it is clear from the context or was used in the previous sentence. The verb "lost" in your example is "говорю".

Я вообще-то *говорю* про то-то и то-то.

As you probably know, the word "to be" is omitted all the time. Sometimes you will see the dash instead of it, sometimes not.

Answer (score 0):

The exact expression with **вообще-то** (actually) with the omitted verb **говорю** (I am speaking) typically occurs *in the middle* of a conversation where the listener has just revealed misunderstanding of the subject. The *ground* for omitting the *verb* here is that the listening person anyway faces the continuing fact of *speaking*.

That very expression is highly unlikely to be seen in a written text since it's a kind of interaction with another person.