Usage of past tense for expressing intended immediate future action
I would be glad if someone could clarify the following:
Can one use verbs in past tense to express an intention to do something in the immediate future? If yes, do my examples make sense?

Example 1: When being asked to do a task, can I answer with:
• «начал (уже)» (in the sense of I will commence with the task right away), or 
• «сделал/выполнил (уже)» (in the sense of consider it done already)?
Example 1 provided with the context that the other person knows that I have not actually already begun/finished the task.
Example 2: Can I use «(Я) пошёл» as an informal goodbye?

It feels natural to me to talk like this, but this could also be a false feeling from my German mother tongue.

https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/16226/why-do-you-say-%D0%AF-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%91%D0%BB-when-should-be-present-tense


When being asked to do a task, can I answer with:

«начал (уже)» (in the sense of I will commence with the task right away)
«сделал/выполнил (уже)» (in the sense of consider it done already)?


You can use it with some verbs ironically, with implied "consider it done", when the fact that you haven't actually started yet is obvious from the context.
It only really works if you physically couldn't have uttered the phrase had you actually done what you're talking about: заснул, пошёл, замолчал and similar:


— Спи давай! — Уже заснул!
— Всё, всё, замолчал!


For начал, сделал etc., this usage is not idiomatic and would be confusing, even if the person knows you're being ironic. It would be better to add считай "consider": считай, уже начал; считай, сделал etc.

Example 2: Can I use «(Я) пошёл» as an informal goodbye?

Yes, you can, and it's actually idiomatic (with most verbs of motion, like я побежал; я поехал etc.)
It entered the mainstream Russian about 70 years ago, before that, it was considered poor style.

Great & clear answer, thanks. One follow up question: Do your examples referring to my Example 1, e.g., «уже заснул» come with a different undertone (e.g., mocking, resigned, …) compared to answering with a simple affirmative answer like «ладно», «буду» etc?

@Truubehüeter: unlike пошёл, уже замолчал and similar is deliberate irony, similar to making a gesture of zipping your lips, locking them with a key and throwing away the key.

There is also the use of the past as a kind of imperative. E.g. if a man puts his arms round a woman and she says руки убрал, it means "take your hands off".

Can we include the expression "поехали!" in these examples?

@Bruno: поехали! (in Gagarin's sense, if that's what you mean) is an imperative, it's different from what the op is asking about.

@Quassnoi Yes, it is what I meant. "поехали! is an imperative" : it is used as an imperative but, from a grammatical viewpoint, isn't it just a past tense (to express an intention to do something in the immediate future)?

@Bruno: sure, but the op was asking about the indicative mood. Пошёл? in the indicative sense is a neutral question, meaning "are you just about to leave?", as in dressed up, taken all your stuff with you and standing in the doorway. It only works with the verbs of motion. In the imperative sense, it would have been an extremely rude command, and it works with any verb.
